# How can I get all text inside paragraph tags that's inside a div element

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

So I'm trying to scrape a news website and get the actual text inside it. My problem right now is that the actual article is divided into several `p` tags who in turn are inside a div tag.

It looks like this:

```
<div>
<p><strong>S</strong>paragraph</p>
<p>paragraph</p>
<h2 class="more-on__heading">heading</h2>
<figure>fig</figure>
<h2>header/h2>
<p>text</p>
<p>text</p>
<p>text</p>
</div>
```

What I tried so far is this:

```
article = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(article.content, 'html.parser')
article_title = soup.find('h1').text
article_author = soup.find('a', class_='author-link').text
article_text = ''
for element in soup.find('div', class_='wysiwyg wysiwyg--all-content css-1vkfgk0'):
    article_text += element.find('p').text
```

But it shows that 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Answer (score 0):

Cause expected output is not that clear from the question - General approch would be to select all `p` in your `div` e.g. with `css selectors` extract the text and `join()` it by what ever you like:

```
article_text = '\n'.join(e.text for e in soup.select('div p'))
```

If you just like to scrape text from siblings of the `h2` in your example use:

```
article_text = '\n'.join(e.text for e in soup.select('h2 ~ p'))
```

or with `find()` and `find_next_siblings()`:

```
article_text = '\n'.join(e.text for e in soup.find('h2').find_next_siblings('p'))
```

###### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''
<div>
<p><strong>S</strong>paragraph</p>
<p>paragraph</p>
<h2 class="more-on__heading">heading</h2>
<figure>fig</figure>
<h2>header/h2>
<p>text</p>
<p>text</p>
<p>text</p>
</div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
article_text = '\n'.join(e.text for e in soup.select('h2 ~ p'))
print(article_text)
```

###### Output

```
text
text
text
```